# How to dynamically change url between contextPath and servletPath, pathInfo etc

Tags: jsp, url, servlets

So guys, i have a web apllication which works with group of expenses, but now it's only one group and the task is to do the following:
Each group has an uuid and i need to generate new id for each user who visit homepage and then url should be like 
[1]: 
So the problem is how to do it possible to work with suck urls, how to do redirects and so on. Ive tried filters and servlets but it gave nothing

Comment: [1]: localhost:8080/myApp/expense-group/(here comes uuid)/(here comes servlet paths and etc)

Comment: Ive made mistake in word "such" in last row :D